# C++ - Having problems defining a variable inside main() function

Tags: c++, variables, ogdf

I am trying to define a variable from an external library in C++, Visual Studio 2010. It only works when I put it outside of the main function.

This code crashes:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <ogdf\basic\Graph.h>
#include <ogdf\basic\graph_generators.h>

int main()
{
   ogdf::Graph g;
   ogdf::randomSimpleGraph(g, 10, 20);
   return 0;
}
```

It gives me an unhandheld exception: Access violation.
However, if it is outside main function, it works without any problem:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <ogdf\basic\Graph.h>
#include <ogdf\basic\graph_generators.h>

ogdf::Graph g;

int main()
{
   ogdf::randomSimpleGraph(g, 10, 20);
   return 0;
}
```

Do you have any how do I fix that? I assume, that it is caused by some kind of linking problem.

EDIT: It looks like the problem is not the initialization of the variable. It throws an exception, when the application exits.

```
int main()
{
ogdf::Graph g; // No problem
ogdf::randomSimpleGraph(g, 10, 20); // No problem
int i; // No problem
std::cin>>i; // No problem
return 0;    // Throws an exception after read i;
```

}

Call stack: [image: Call STack]

The output is:
First-chance exception at 0x0126788f in graphs.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Unhandled exception at 0x0126788f in graphs.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Comment: It probably have something to do with that global variables are zero-initialized, while local variables have indeterminate values. What if you explicitly zero-initialize `g` when declared locally?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: but ogdf::Graph is a class and the constructor hopefully does the initialisation stuff. Documentation is [here](http://www.ogdf.net/doc-ogdf/classogdf_1_1_graph.html)

Comment: Can you also post the stack dump. It would be interesting **where** the exception is raised, and because of which address.

Comment: Problems in the destructor?

Comment: You could try with new/delete and verify if the destructor of g throws, or if its some global object in the linked library that throws  on program exit. Could be a bug in the library where a pointer to g is kept somewhere in a global var that will access it in the destructor.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I will try with another release, and reinstall Visual Studio, maybe it'll fix the problem.

Comment: Reinstalling Visual Studio will certainly not help you at all! The library you are using probably has a bug as @Bgie suggests.

Comment: @user3382896: so, any progress on that?

Answer (score 5):

Works on my machine™.

Esoteric errors like that are often a result of binary incompability. Basically, because of different compiler/preprocessor options, effective headers that your code and the library "see" are different.

For instance, if you have a library with following header code:

```
class Foo
{
#ifdef FOO_DEBUG
    int debug_variable;
#endif
    int variable;
};
```

Library function:

```
void bar(Foo& foo)
{
    std::cout << foo.variable;
}
```

And client code:

```
Foo foo;
foo.variable = 666;
bar(foo);
```

If `FOO_DEBUG` is not in sync amongst client and the library, this will possibly crash and burn -- `variable` will have different expected offset.

In your case, I suspect one of the following may be true:

- You have built the ogdf with different compiler than your code
- If not, you ogdf and your code have different build configurations (Release vs Debug)
- Both are debug, but you have defined `OGDF_DEBUG` (as recommended [here](http://www.ogdf.net/doku.php/tech%3ainstallvcc))
- You have different "Struct Member Alignment" setting